# Two classes to validate and store an e-mail address

Tags: php, validation, comparative-review, email, properties

I'm trying to improve my limited knowledge in PHP (7) and I wrote these two simple classes as a proof of concept.

They both have just one (private) property *->email* and they run validation before setting a value for it (unless it's *null*).

They are both supposed to run at *business-tier*

GtokenA uses magic methods and is more strict than GtokenB. It does not allow to set any property that is not declared.

```
<?php

class GtokenA
{
    /**
     * @var string  $email
     */
    protected $email;

    public function __construct($email = null)
    {
        $this->__set('email', $email);
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        if(property_exists($this,$property)){
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value)
    {

        if (!property_exists($this, $property)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("The class " . get_class($this) . " does not have the property " . $property);
        }

        switch ($property) {
            case 'email':
                // a null value is acceptable
                // otherwise I need the email to be a valid recipient
                $validator = new \EmailValidator\Validator();
                try {
                    if(!is_null($value) && !$validator->isSendable($value)) {
                        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Wrong value for ->$property");
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Wrong value for ->$property : " . $e->getMessage());
                }

                break;
        }

        $this->$property = $value;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

GtokenB uses setters and getters:

```
<?php

class GtokenB
{
    /**
     * @var string  $email
     */
    private $email;

    public function __construct($email = null)
    {
        $this->setEmail($email);
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email = null)
    {
            // a null email is acceptable
            // otherwise I need the email to be a valid recipient
            $validator = new \EmailValidator\Validator();
            try {
                if(!is_null($email) && !$validator->isSendable($email)) {
                    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Wrong email for ->email");
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException("Wrong email for ->email : " . $e->getMessage());
            }

        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I also wrote some (hopefully meaningful) tests for my first time ever.

GtokenA tests:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/src/models/gtokenB.php';
/**
 * GtokenA test case.
 */
class GtokenBTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers __construct()
     */
    public function test__construct_withArguments()
    {
        $email = "abuse@google.com";
        $gtoken = new GtokenB($email);
        $this->assertEquals($email, $gtoken->getEmail());
    }

    /**
    * @covers __construct()
    **/
    public function test_construct_noArguments()
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenB();
        $gtoken->setEmail(null);
        $this->assertEquals(null, $gtoken->getEmail());
    }

    public function validEmailStringProvider(){
        return array(
            'valid_1' => array("k123@google.com", "k123@google.com"),
            'valid_2' => array("abuse@google.com", "abuse@google.com"),
            'valid_3' => array(null,null),
            'valid_4' => array("doesnotexist@google.com", "doesnotexist@google.com"),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @covers Gtoken::__set()
     * @dataProvider validEmailStringProvider
     */
    public function test_setter_Email($email, $expected)
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenB();
        $gtoken->setEmail($email);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $gtoken->getEmail());
    }

    public function invalidEmailString()
    {
        return array(
            "invalid_1" => array("email-examplecom"),
            "invalid_2" => array("email-example.com"),
            "invalid_3" => array("email\\\"@example.com"),
            "invalid_4" => array("email@example!.com"),
            "invalid_6" => array("email@example$.com"),
            "invalid_7" => array("email@example.com"),
            "invalid_8" => array("email\@example.com"),
            "invalid_9" => array("email@example.com."),
            "invalid_10" => array("nospam@example.com"),
            'integer' => array(123, null),
            'array_0' => array(array(), null),
            'array_1' => array(array('email@example.com'), null),
            );
    }

    /**
    * @covers Gtoken::__set()
    * @expectedException UnexpectedValueException
    * @dataProvider invalidEmailString
    **/
    public function test_setter_Email_throwsUnexpectedValueException($email)
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenB();
        $gtoken->setEmail($email);
    }
}
```

GtokenB tests:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/src/models/gtokenA.php';
/**
 * GtokenA test case.
 */
class GtokenATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers __construct()
     */
    public function test__construct_withArguments()
    {
        $email = "abuse@google.com";
        $gtoken = new GtokenA($email);
        $this->assertEquals($email, $gtoken->email);
    }

    /**
    * @covers __construct()
    **/
    public function test_construct_noArguments()
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenA();
        $gtoken->email = null;
        $this->assertEquals(null, $gtoken->email);
    }

    /**
    * @covers __set()
    * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
    **/
    public function test_set_notExistentProperty()
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenA();
        $gtoken->kk = null;
    }

    public function validEmailStringProvider(){
        return array(
            'valid_1' => array("k123@google.com", "k123@google.com"),
            'valid_2' => array("abuse@google.com", "abuse@google.com"),
            'valid_3' => array(null,null),
            'valid_4' => array("doesnotexist@google.com", "doesnotexist@google.com"),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @covers Gtoken::__set()
     * @dataProvider validEmailStringProvider
     */
    public function test_setter_Email($email, $expected)
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenA();
        $gtoken->email = $email;
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $gtoken->email);
    }

    public function invalidEmailString()
    {
        return array(
            "invalid_1" => array("email-examplecom"),
            "invalid_2" => array("email-example.com"),
            "invalid_3" => array("email\\\"@example.com"),
            "invalid_4" => array("email@example!.com"),
            "invalid_6" => array("email@example$.com"),
            "invalid_7" => array("email@example.com"),
            "invalid_8" => array("email\@example.com"),
            "invalid_9" => array("email@example.com."),
            "invalid_10" => array("nospam@example.com"),
            'integer' => array(123, null),
            'array_0' => array(array(), null),
            'array_1' => array(array('email@example.com'), null),
            );
    }

    /**
    * @covers Gtoken::__set()
    * @expectedException UnexpectedValueException
    * @dataProvider invalidEmailString
    **/
    public function test_setter_Email_throwsUnexpectedValueException($email)
    {
        $gtoken = new GtokenA();
        $gtoken->email = $email;
    }
}
```

---

I prefer GtokenA by far. It feels more elegant in the usage ( `$obj->email = "value"` instead of `$obj->setEmail("value")` ) but, most important, it's strict and I could write and run this test:

```
/**
* @covers __set()
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
**/
public function test_set_notExistentProperty()
{
    $gtoken = new GtokenA();
    $gtoken->kk = null;
}
```

But maybe this is just a personal preference that brings no value to the code.

**Questions:**

- How do you rate my code?
- Would you suggest any improvement?
- Do I use Exceptions in a meaningful way?

Comment: I've removed your question about the unit tests, since you haven't included that code in the question itself.

Comment: If you want your unit tests to be reviewed, then include the code in the question too.

Comment: sorry forgot to paste the links!!

Comment: We don't review code in links, only code that is embedded directly in the question itself.

Comment: oh now I see! I did that to keep the question shorter. I'm going to edit.

Answer (score 3):

The first example (you called it "GtokenA") is a complete garbage. In a real world situation, your class would have more than 1 parameter, which means that your *magic method* would grow in complexity and, when you return to that code in 3 month for maintenance, you will have forgotten all about how that magic worked.

As for second approach .. well ...

- From the constructor it is clear, that "email" is an optional parameter, but, if I don't pass it a valid email, then it blows up in my face. That doesn't really makes sense.
- Why are you hard-coding the validator? Instead of constructor accepting an email, it should instead be expecting a validator to be passed in. What if you have **gasp** other classes, that also need a validator?
- The constructors should never contain any computational logic. It become almost completely untestable.
- What about testing the validator? How do you intent to isolate it from "Gtoken" classes?

So .. my rating would be: *"you started to learn about unit tests like 2 days ago, right?"*

**About improving this mess:**

There are actually two approaches for validating an entity:

- you can validate it on each setter  - which is kinda nice, when you can always be sure, that the entity at all time is in a valid state
- have a separate `isValid()` method - which comes in handy, when you have to validate more complex conditions .. like country-city combinations, where you need one to validate the other and vice versa

In either case, when you have a codebase, which would expect a "full valid instance" to be produced, it's preferable to have a separate `Builder` class, that becomes responsible for assembling the dependencies, initializing the cl;as, passing the values and making sure that all is valid, before returning a prepared instance to the rest of your codebase ...

Comment: I started almost everything a couple of weeks ago :-) Later I will spend some time on what you have wrote and brb

Comment: about testing \EmailValidator\Validator . It's a package from packagist with its own unit tests, that's why I didn't write tests on it. But in my unit tests I have tested several cases of validation: are they complete garbage?

Answer (score 1):

> It feels more elegant in the usage ( `$obj->email = "value"` instead of `$obj->setEmail("value")` )

It's mostly a matter of preference, but I would strongly disagree with this. The normal `setEmail` approach makes it very clear that this is a method that is applied to a specific instance.

This is logically different than your preferred approach, which looks as if it were only setting a value (which it actually isn't! It's also validating).

Additionally, your prefered approach looks as if it would break encapsulation (even though it doesn't).

Other than that, I would mostly agree with @tereško. Additionally:

- what's a `gtoken`? Write the `g` part out to make it clearer.
- What `Exception` are you catching? It's very unclear when this might happen or why it might happen. At the very least you should catch the specific exceptions, not the general exception. I could also imagine that exceptions are thrown which do not mean that an email is invalid (such as wrong server email config, timeouts, and who knows what else).
- your indentation is off, making your code harder to read.
- your comment is not really needed. I can tell from the code that a null email is ok. What a comment should explain is why this is the case (it's rather unexpected). As it is, the comment would be better as a PHPDoc method comment instead of an in-code comment.
- you could make it more explicit that null is an allowed email by extracting that check to the beginning, eg: `if (is_null($email)) { return $this; // valid email because X }`. Now your if is also simplified.

Comment: both the classes are just a proof of concept I'm not really trying to do anything. I'm studying and writing code upon what I learn. I admit, though, that Gtoken is supposed to be a class handling Google Tokens (request new / revoke / refresh)

Comment: @wwr In that case, `GoogleToken` would be a better name :) If you want to keep it generic for now, `Token` might be acceptable as well. The main thing is to not keep a reader wondering what g might stand for.

Comment: why do you say "indentation is off"? I even ran phpcbf (PSR2) before posting. Could you please point out what's wrong with it? I really don't see it.

Comment: @wwr sorry, it's just that part of `GtokenB:setEmail` is indented too much (it's a very minor thing and doesn't really hurt readability that much, but I thought I'd mention it anyways).